# Unable to get Splunk query SID

Tags: python, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk

Below is my code snippet:

```
search='index="someindex" earliest=27/01/2019:0:0:0 latest=27/01/2018:23:59:00'

data = {'search': search, 'max_count':'10000000'}
response = requests.post('https://something:8089/services/search/jobs',
                         auth=('usr', 'pwd'), data=data, verify=False)
#print(response)                         
root = ET.fromstring(response.text)
#print(root)
for tag in root:
    job_id = tag.text
    print(job_id)
print(job_id)
```

I'm getting 400 in response and an error in printing `job_id`.

Answer (score 0):

The search string should start with `search` keyword, if you're searching on an index.

Modify the search string:

```
search='search index="someindex" earliest=27/01/2019:0:0:0 latest=27/01/2018:23:59:00'
```